# WooCommerce Payment Gateway integration to external page like PayPal

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment

I would like to add a new payment gateway POS integration to my Wordpress WooCommerce page it will be an external form based payment page so i dont need to SSL or something. I have the documentation from bank but how can i integrate it into WooCommerce?

It will be more like PayPal when user click on purschase and select My_New_Payment-Gateway it will redirect them into the Banks Payment Page.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an extension for WooCommerce to handle it.  You can look at their existing extensions as samples and just change them accordingly to use your gateway instead of PayPal or whatever sample you're looking at.

WooCommerce is built using WordPress standards, so it works exactly the same as building any other WP plugin.